# Digital signal processing of audio signals

Tags: audio

i have recently started working on audio signals. On converting an audio signal into digital (ADC), how will I know the frequency of the original signal..  I mean Digital signal is just an array of numbers and there will be no information about frequency.. please help me this..

Comment: Is this question more relevant on the Electronics stack-exchange?

Comment: A digital representation of a waveform is (most often) a vector of numbers (samples) and an associated sampling rate - the number of samples per second.  Your analog-to-digital converter (ADC) hardware will have sampled at some specific rate (e.g., 8000 or 44100 samples/sec); you need to know what that is to properly interpret the vector of samples.

Comment: belongs to dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can get the frequency back (assuming its not aliased because of incorrect sampling) by analysing the magnitude plot of the DFT, and converting that prominent digital frequency to continuous. This is very google-able.

Answer (score 0):

There is something that should be understood:
If you meet the Nyquist criterion - there is only one way to reconstruct the original signal
(using ideal reconstruction filter).

In other words, if you meet Nyquist criterion the discrete signal has **exactly** all the information as the continuous signal, which means it has also all the information of the signal spectrum (Fourier Transform).

We know that the difference between time domain and frequency domain is all about representation.

(of course this is true in ideal sampling and reconstruction - in real cases - this is not far from being true if Nyquist critetion holds to a good approximation)